# What is the best line algorithm to use in drawing application?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, curve, bezier

What would be considered the best algorithm for line drawing in a program like photoshop or gimp?

I've been playing around with bresenham's line algorithm and I find that the lines don't render very well because it does not pick up on the natural flow (curves) of the pen.

i.e:
[image]

What is the best way to draw smooth lines from user input with no post editing? Can some form of bezier curve be used? 
Is there a standard accepted algorithm for this kind of thing or just a general idea of how it should be done?

Answer (score 2):

There are different kinds of [splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) which can be used for this, where [Bézier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve) are the the best-known. Basically, two kinds of splines are distinguished, namely interpolating splies (which go through the control points) and approximating splines (which are not required to go through the control points, but try to minimize a suitable difference to the line segments). For evaluation of Bézier curves, an algorithm by [De Casteljau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm) for evaluation of the [Bernstein polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial) can be used, although other schemes will perhaps work as well.